# rails postgresql database connection

Tags: postgresql, sudo, rails-postgresql

I am trying to use a postgresql database for my rails app.

I followed the tutorials provided in this link:

```
http://blog.crowdint.com/2010/10/27/working-with-postgresql-and-rails3.html
```

I successfully installed postgresql with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contrib libpq-dev libpgsql-ruby libgda-4.0-postgres libpq-dev
```

When I reached the line to create a user I entered this command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
```

But after I entered a password for root it gave me an error saying

```
env: -u: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why the error popped up?

Comment: This is not an answer to your direct question but if you are not already using it I would strongly recommend downloading and using PGadmin, the main postgres gui management tool that will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the environment/path may be messed up for your user. I'm not sure if you're running on mac or linux/unix but I found a post from the Ubuntu forums that may be related to your problem:

[sudo is broken](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1430563)

I'm not sure if alias'ing sudo (page 2 reply)

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$path'
```

is the best permanent solution but it fixes it for him.  I have no such alias on my sudo so I'm thinking there's a better solution via profile / export command and would invite someone to provide a better answer.

Hope this helps